# PL/SQL FETCH NEXT or rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Not much to elaborate, what should be used? they looks to perform the same task.

rownum?

```
select * from IDENTIFIKATOR
  where rownum <= 10;
```

or fetch next?

```
select * from IDENTIFIKATOR
  FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Upon further expection rownum, might on the surface look to be faster

```
select * from (select * from IDENTIFIKATOR order by IDENTIFIKATORID )
  where rownum <= 10;
```

has a cardinality of 10 and a cost of 10 (plain execution time of 0.15-0.2s (asc vs desc))

```
select * from IDENTIFIKATOR 
order by IDENTIFIKATORID 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

has a cardinality of 10 and a cost of 158869 (plain execution time of 1.9s-2s(asc vs desc))

Comment: I'd say FETCH NEXT as it is ANSI SQL (and more or less portable.)

Comment: Both does same but we cannot run same in same Oracle version. `FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;` only in 12C version. Its not compatible with lower versions

Comment: Read https://blog.dbi-services.com/oracle-rownum-vs-rownumber-and-12c-fetch-first/  to get an explanation of this behaviour

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Oracle 12c+, then I would suggest that you get used to the `FETCH` clause.  It is ANSI-standard syntax and available in other databases.  Plus, it is more flexible.  For instance, you can do:

```
select i.*
from IDENTIFIKATOR i
order by col2 desc
fetch first 10 rows only;
```

And, it supports the `OFFSET` modifier.

Doing this using `rownum` requires a subquery.

On the other hand, if your code needs to work with earlier versions of Oracle, then `rownum` is basically your only choice.

Comment: i just looked at the execution plan (on those exact queries in my question) and the fetch had a cost of 41626 while the rownum had a cost of 4. Not sure if i understand the cost properly but lower is better?

Comment: When i have something in the WHERE the cost goes down to 3 for both queries but cardinality is 10 for fetch while it being 1 on rownum

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian . . . Perhaps Oracle has not completed cost estimations for `FETCH`.  It is a new feature.  Do the queries themselves show a difference in performance?

Comment: We have a workload im working on tuning, il start it with rownum as a benchmark experiment.

Comment: Hmm it looks to be faster using rownum an hour or so faster, it is atleas not slower than fetch. The gain is either marginal or within the error range for our workload that takes 24 ish hours.